# How do I make plain text act as a button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I was wondering what is the simplest way of making just plain text act as a button (with minimal html). Text:
    `<li class="indiv-nav" ><a target="_blank" href="/">About</a></li>`

I need the text about to perform that of:

`<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Press me please!" /></div>`

Sorry if this is a "stupid" question but, I'm still learning and I find it crazy how theres no "simpler" solution than those I found from googling.

Comment: yes as much jQuery as possible or css but preferably less HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="button">Submit</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").bind("click",function(){
        $("#idOfYourForm").submit();  // consider idOfYourForm `id` of your form which you are going to submit
    });
});
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("idOfYourForm").submit();
};
```

Comment: Thank you I Think this'll work after a few changes but, would this work even though there is no <form> tags associated with this?

Comment: @user1 you're welcome . You can't submit data without `form` tags , in this way you can only make interact changes with `JavaScript`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (without jQuery), but you'll need a **form** tag:

```
<form name="myform">
<span onclick="document.myform.submit();">submit this</span> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you want to do on what solution you can use.

regular button:

```
$("li.indiv-nav a").click(function(){
          /* do something here*/
          window.location = 'about.html';
    });
```

or submit form:

```
$("li.indiv-nav a").click(function(){
          $('#formid').submit();  
    });
```

check out a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPXmX/)

Answer (score -1):

You could use CSS `appearance` attribute.

Set it to `appearance:button;` for your link.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/suw8R/2/)

OR

(Alternate) =>  [**Make button looks like a link**](http://jsfiddle.net/suw8R/6/)

Comment: But, it will look like a button? I want it to act like a button but appear as plain text or as it would be on its own like a hyperlink I geuss?

Comment: @user1, you should style the button to look like plain text.

Comment: @user1: zzzzBov is right,you can make a button looks like a link if you want. See the added fiddle in answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
form.submit()
```

You need to find a way to reference the form you want to submit, but once you have the form object, you can just call `.submit()` to submit it.

You can then add it as an `onclick` attribute, or bind it later, but this is basically what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by act like a button but you can always style it using CSS. Just give it round corners and hover effects if that is what you mean. You can learn more [here](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/01/10/pressed-button-state-with-css3/).

But if you mean you want to disable the link and do something else instead, you can do so using javascript. Just include a javascript file, and prevent the default action of the link. Like:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //do what you want here
  }):
});
```